# How to run custom code in the main thread of Cocoa applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

I'm a windows developer and I'm having a hard time understanding the right way to run code in the 
NSApplication's main thread.

Most of my code is running in a cvdisplaylink thread (it's an opengl app)
THe problem is that I can't call things like NSOpenPanel from it - it crashes the app and warns about only running stuff like this from the main thread.

It's fine, but the main thread is completely opaque as far as I understand, and I can only make it do things with events. The NSApp sendAction method sounded promising - because I could explicitly specify which method to call. But it didn't 'send' any thing, it just called this method directly from the same thread.

Am I understanding this right? Do I have to push some sort of a custom event (perhaps NSEventTypeApplicationDefined) to the main thread queue for this to work properly?
And if so, how to I respond to custom events like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to call a method of an Obj C object, the old school Cocoa way (which still works) is to use performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

E.g. to hide a window by calling its "orderOut:" method you would do this.

```
[theWindow performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(orderOut:) 
                            withObject:nil 
                         waitUntilDone:NO];
```